# Проблема с установкой модулей Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, модули

Не устанавливаются модули python. При попытке установки любого модуля ошибка: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement *название модуля* (from version: none)" и "ERROR: No matching distribution found for *название модуля*" Пример на картинке ниже
В чём проблема и как решить[image: Пример ошибки]

Comment: Какая версия питона и pip используется? Выполните команды `python -V` и `pip -V`

Comment: 3.9.2 позже 3.8.8. На обоих версиях одинаковые ошибки

Answer (score -1):

Возможно ошибка заключается в том, что при установке Python не была нажата галочка "Add Python (версия) to PATH". Она нужна, чтобы ты мог вызвать Python из любого места(консоли).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, python добавлен в переменную окружения PATH